# Customize dataframe in R

Tags: r

Below is the dataframe in R, I currently have.

```
A       B   C   D
gd      3   65  gd
ggfh    4   tg  dg
```

Is there a way to get below output (basically adding a row(merged row) above the header
[image]

Comment: Do you want to have a new header and change the header to first row?.  Perhaps, you can check `kable` if you want a multiline header

Comment: You want an image, a html code, latex code, or something different?

Comment: Not the image. I am using this table kable function inside rmd report (a pdf document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the package `kableExtra` you can solve the problem for example as follows:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)



df <- data.frame(
  A = c('gd', 'ggfh'), 
  B = 3:4, 
  C = c(65, 'tg'), 
  D = c('gd', 'dg')
)

kable(df) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Main" = 1, "456" = 2, "54" = 1))
```

Comment: AWESOME THANKS. One last clarificaiton. If I need to make the 54 reactive. For example ````able(df) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Main" = 1, "456" = 2, sum(4+5) = 1))````. I am just making it reactive. I am getting error. Can we solve this?

Comment: I think, it's because the vector `c("Main" = 1, "456" = 2, sum(4+5) = 1)` must contain a character vector plus the colspan. Check `?add_header_above`. The argument `header` corresponds to `c("Main" = 1, "456" = 2, sum(4+5) = 1)`.

Comment: If my answer helps, you may up-vote my answer above. Could be helpful for people with similar questions.